# Algorithm to find a specific element's coordinate in a spiral

Tags: algorithm

Here is a spiral, numbers are aligned this way 
[image: or]

and the element `1` ( in the center) is located in `(0,0)` Coordinates;

`2` is `(1,0)`

`3` is `(1,1)`

`4` is `(0,1)`

`5` is `(-1,1)`

`6` is `(-1,0)`

`7` is `(-1,-1)`

`8` is `(0,-1)`

`9` is `(1,-1)`

`10` is `(2,-1)`

`11` is `(2,0)`
and so on ...

We want to find the index the nth element; 73 => (?,?) `e.g. 10 => (2,-1)`

I'd written this algorithm that simulates the spiral, and generates the whole sequence to that number, therefore I can get the desired element's coordinates; here it is in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mhmdrz_a/pen/YzywGKW); here is the snippet ( hover over cells to see their index )

```js
//-- displaying
document.querySelector("#root").style.display = "flex";
document.querySelector("#root").style.height = "100vh";
document.querySelector("#root").style.justifyContent = "center";
document.querySelector("#root").style.alignItems = "center";

let borderStyle = "red";
let res = maze("list", 73);
//console.log(res);
let rafCounter = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(putItInPlace);


function maze(queryType, n) {
  let directions = ["→", "↑", "←", "↓"];
  let directionChangeCounter = 0;
  let turnLength = 1;
  let latestCell = { x: 0, y: 0, value: 1 };
  let output = [latestCell];
  for (let total = 0; total < n; null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < turnLength && total < n; i++) {
      let newCell = { ...latestCell, value: latestCell.value + 1 };
      switch (directions[directionChangeCounter % 4]) {
        case "→":
          newCell.x = latestCell.x + 1;
          break;
        case "↑":
          newCell.y = latestCell.y + 1;
          break;
        case "←":
          newCell.x = latestCell.x - 1;
          break;
        case "↓":
          newCell.y = latestCell.y - 1;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      latestCell = newCell;
      newCell.DxC = directionChangeCounter * turnLength;
      newCell.isLastInTurn = i + 1 === turnLength;
      newCell.direction = directions[directionChangeCounter % 4];
      newCell.directionChangeCounter = directionChangeCounter;
      output.push(newCell);
      total++;
    }
    directionChangeCounter++;
    if (directionChangeCounter % 2 === 0) {
      turnLength++;
    }
  }
  return output;
}


function putItInPlace() {
  let cell = res[rafCounter];
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = cell.value;
  span.title = `x: ${cell.x} y: ${cell.y} dcc: ${cell.directionChangeCounter}`;
  span.style.position = "absolute";
  span.style.display = "flex";
  span.style.justifyContent = "center";
  span.style.alignItems = "center";
  span.style.border = "2px solid grey";
  span.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  let size = 30;
  span.style.width = size + "px";
  span.style.height = size + "px";
  if (cell.direction === "←") {
    addBorderTop(span);
    if (cell.isLastInTurn) addBorderLeft(span);
  }
  if (cell.direction === "→") {
    addBorderBottom(span);
    if (cell.isLastInTurn) addBorderRight(span);
  }
  if (cell.direction === "↑") {
    addBorderRight(span);
    if (cell.isLastInTurn) addBorderTop(span);
  }
  if (cell.direction === "↓") {
    addBorderLeft(span);
    if (cell.isLastInTurn) addBorderBottom(span);
  }
  if (cell.value === 1) {
    addBorderBottom(span);
    addBorderTop(span);
    addBorderLeft(span);
  }
  const multplier = 34;
  span.style.transform = `translate(${cell.x * multplier}px, ${
    -cell.y * multplier
  }px)`;
  document.querySelector("#root").appendChild(span);
  rafCounter++;
  if (rafCounter < res.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(putItInPlace);
  }
}

function addBorderTop(el) {
  el.style.borderTopColor = borderStyle;
}
function addBorderBottom(el) {
  el.style.borderBottomColor = borderStyle;
}
function addBorderRight(el) {
  el.style.borderRightColor = borderStyle;
}
function addBorderLeft(el) {
  el.style.borderLeftColor = borderStyle;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**So** is there any way to **find** the **coordinates** of a desired **elements** **without** **generating** the whole **sequence**? maybe an `O(1)` solution? I'm not looking for the exact implementation in any specific language; Pseudocode is just fine; thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you see that there is squares in it? top-left "corners" 4, 16, 36, 64, 100, ie 2^2, 4^2, 6^2, 8^2, 10^2, etc ? May not be difficult to find where your number is... This will at least lead to an O(sqrt(n)) solution.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yeah, let me add another one; the offset of two element in corner increments by `8` every time; e.g. `13-3=10`, `31-13=18`, `57-31=26`, `91-57=34` .... so, `10, 18, 26, 34` => two adjacent element difference `8, 8, 8, ..` there are some patterns in some rows, but how we add them up together to one formula to calculate the coordinates

Comment: It's *Ulam spiral*, see https://web.archive.org/web/20141202041502/https://danpearcymaths.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/infinity-programming-in-geogebra-and-failing-miserably/ for coordinates inverse; you can have close formula and `O(1)` solution, but you have t work with *complex* numbers

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that was pretty nice dude thanks for that; btw is it possible to implement that complex number stuff in javascript?

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A: why not? E.g. https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/complex_numbers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this code help you. You can find relation from spiral function..

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void spiral(int n) {
    int k = ceil((sqrt(n) - 1) / 2);
    int t = 2 * k + 1;
    int m = pow(t, 2);
    t = t - 1;
    if (n >= m - t) {
        printf("%d %d\n",k - (m - n), -k);
        return;
    }else {
        m = m - t;
    }
    if (n >= m - t) {
       printf("%d %d\n", -k, -k + (m - n));
        return;
    }  else {
        m = m - t;
    }
    if (n >= m - t) {
        printf("%d %d\n", -k + (m - n), k);
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d %d\n",k, k - (m - n - t));
        return;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        spiral(n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163080/on-a-two-dimensional-grid-is-there-a-formula-i-can-use-to-spiral-coordinates-in) to get better understand.

Comment: I'd tried to run it in [cpp.shell](http://cpp.sh/) btw I wsan't successful, how can i run it ?

Comment: extension will be `.cpp`,,, you can run code any online compiler.... try here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: epic; thanks for the time; and that link was super helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is the O(1) solution, The javascript version of accepted answer;

```js
console.log(spiral(26));

function spiral(n) {
    let k = Math.ceil((Math.sqrt(n) - 1) / 2);
    let t = (2 * k + 1) ;
    let m = Math.pow(t, 2);
    t = t - 1;
    if (n >= m - t) {
        return [k - (m - n), -k];
    }else {
        m = m - t;
    }
    if (n >= m - t) {
       return  [-k, -k + (m - n)];
    }  else {
        m = m - t;
    }
    if (n >= m - t) {
        return  [-k + (m - n), k];
    }
    else {
        return [k,k - (m - n - t)];
    }
}
```